# How to call wgpicasa pro component into module in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I am trying to get **wgpicasa pro** component into my module through **component anywhere plugin** but sometime working good but sometime not working. So anyone tell me how can i call component into module without using **component anywhere plugin**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing this we need to use short code of wgpicasa pro in custom HTML module and need to enable prepare content to get content by short code without installing any component.

Screen Shots:

[image: Short Code Img]

[image]